# Tfidfvectorizer from sklearn - how to get matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I would like to get matrix out of Tfidfvectorizer object from sklearn. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
text = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
        "The dog.",
        "The fox"]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
```

Here is what I tried and got back errors:

```
vectorizer.toarray()
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-117-76146e626284> in <module>()   
> ----> 1 vectorizer.toarray()
>
> AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'toarray'
> ```

another attempt

```
vectorizer.todense()
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-118-6386ee121184> in <module>()
> ----> 1 vectorizer.todense()
>
> AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'todense'
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [`vectorizer.fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform) returns the term-document matrix that you want to obtain. So save what it returns, and use `todense`, as it will be in sparse format:

> **Returns**: X : sparse matrix, [n_samples, n_features].
>   Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.

```
a = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
a.todense()

matrix([[0.36388646, 0.27674503, 0.27674503, 0.36388646, 0.36388646,
         0.36388646, 0.36388646, 0.42983441],
        [0.        , 0.78980693, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.61335554],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.78980693, 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.61335554]])
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform) itself returns a document term matrix. So, you do:

```
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
```

`matrix.todense()` use to convert the sparse to dense matrix. 
`matrix.shape` will give you the shape of matrix.